# PySpark: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable in dataframe operations

Tags: python, pyspark

I am reading files from a folder in a loop and creating dataframes from these.
However, I am getting this weird error `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`.
Please find the code here:

```
for yr in range (2014,2018):
  cat_bank_yr = sqlCtx.read.csv(cat_bank_path+str(yr)+'_'+h1+'bank.csv000',sep='|',schema=schema)
  cat_bank_yr=cat_bank_yr.withColumn("cat_ledger",trim(lower(col("cat_ledger"))))
  cat_bank_yr=cat_bank_yr.withColumn("category",trim(lower(col("category"))))
```

The code runs for one iteration and then stops at the line

```
cat_bank_yr=cat_bank_yr.withColumn("cat_ledger",trim(lower(col("cat_ledger"))))
```

with the above error.

Can anyone help out?

Comment: Do you import trim, col, and lower from the PySpark.sql.functions module? Can you add your import line as well? Your code looks fine, but your functions might be overwritten by something else, e.g. a line like `trim="my_new_string`

Comment: can  you please post the full code?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your code looks fine - if the error indeed happens in the line you say it happens, you probably accidentally overwrote one of the PySpark function with a string.

To check this, put the following line directly above your for loop and see whether the code runs without an error now:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, trim, lower
```

Alternatively, double-check whether the code really stops in the line you said, or check whether col, trim, lower are what you expect them to be by calling them like this:

```
col
```

should return

> function pyspark.sql.functions._create_function.._(col)

Comment: You are awesome! I had a line like this: `pivot_cols=[col for col in cat_bank_yr.columns]`. Never expected it to cause problem! Changed the variable name, all well now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In my case the error was simpler, but related - I hade a date_format variable declared and I was further down in the code using something like: 
.withColumn('DATE', date_format('DATE_ONE', 'd')) \

Answer (score 5):

There is another possible reason. In your scripts, you may use col as a variable. This can also result in the error message.

Answer (score 3):

In the import section use:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
```

Then in the code wherever using `col`, use `F.col` so your code would be:

```
# on top/header part of code 
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
    
for yr in range (2014,2018):
    cat_bank_yr = sqlCtx.read.csv(cat_bank_path+str(yr)+'_'+h1+'bank.csv000',sep='|',schema=schema)
    cat_bank_yr=cat_bank_yr.withColumn("cat_ledger",trim(lower(F.col("cat_ledger"))))
    cat_bank_yr=cat_bank_yr.withColumn("category",trim(lower(F.col("category"))))
```

Hope this will work. Good luck.

Comment: I edited your answer to use code blocks.  Please use the [ { } ] button when editing or refer to:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Using `F.col` instead of importing `col` directly is indeed a nice way to prevent accidentally overwriting the PySpark functions.